# Dynamic selection widget with fixed row count and an option to expand

Tags: flutter, dart, dynamic, selection-sort, multipleselection

I have an issue building the widget in the pic,
I'm trying to build a **dynamic selection widget with an option to expand**.
**Max row is 3** but there is no constrain on how much children the row could have, it could have 2 or 3 or 4.
I can do that dynamicly but the issue is in the last row, if there is more widgets to show I have to show a **more** button that expands the list to full length.[image]

I tried every posssible dynamic widget but non of them can help me decide whether the widgets number exceeds the availbe space.

Comment: Try Wrap widget instead of Row